# CallbackQueryHandler or ConversationHandler for a message sent from bot class

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Using [python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html), I have a bot running with very similar settings as for the [other examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/README.md). On the other side i have parallel processes that allow me to send messages to users interacting with the bot periodically. The parallel proccess communicates with the users using:

```
bot = Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
def get_button_options():
    keyboard = [[ InlineKeyboardButton("reply", callback_data='reply),]]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    return reply_markup
bot.send_message(chat_id=self.telegram_id, text=text, reply_markup=get_button_options())
```

The thing is, even if I'm capable to send messages to the user, the above code does not allow the user to interact with the bot (By that I mean that, once the user presses the button, the bot doesn't execute any callback). This is because I need either a [CallbackQueryHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html) or [ConversationHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html?highlight=Conversation) within the bot.

However for the `ConversationHandler` I don't seem to find any appropiate entry_point, since it is a message sent from a parallel process. On the other hand, using the following `CallbackQueryHandler` (taken from [the example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py)) in the main bot doesn't seem to have any effect:

```
def button(update: Update, _: CallbackContext) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    query.answer()

    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")
```

in the main function, I have added the handler using `updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))`

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: The question has been answered in the PTB support group: https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/456478 TL;DR: Use the `CallbackQueryHandler` as `entry_point` for the `ConversationHandler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @CallMeStag, the solution is the following:

```
ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CallbackQueryHandler(button)])
```

the correct entry point is a `CallbackQueryHandler`, so then it captures the selected button