# Trigger ConversationHandler without a command?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am already 3 months stuck in this function of my future telegram bot :(

I want to use the  `ConversationHandler` for my situation. The code currently send the user a message to solve math. Then the user should enter the result. All is working fine!

The `ConversationHandler` only gets triggerd when the user runs it directly with the /start command in the Telegram Bot.

Now I did add a `InlineKeyboardButton`. When the user clicks a button the `InlineKeyboardButton` gives callback data to the `button()` function. Also here is all working fine. Now my question:

Is there a way to run the `ConversationHandler` directly from the `button()` function? (look at the comments in the code to see where it should be running)

**Code without Buttons:**

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler


FIRST_STEP, SECOND_STEP = range(2)

conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        FIRST_STEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, first_step)],
        SECOND_STEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, second_step)],
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)

def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='2 + 2 = ?', 
        parse_mode='markdown')
    return FIRST_STEP

def cancel(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='2 + 2 = ?')
    return ConversationHandler.END

def first_step(bot, update):
    if update.message.text != '4':
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='Sorry try again to enter a valid input.')
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='2 + 2 = ?')
        return FIRST_STEP
    else:
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='The answer is right, you are in the next step')
        return SECOND_STEP

def second_step(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='Correct answer', 
        parse_mode='markdown')
    return ConversationHandler.END
```

**Button Code Snippet:**

```
def button(update, context):
    """
    callback method handling button press
    """
    bot: Bot = context.bot
    # getting the callback query
   
    query: CallbackQuery = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
   
    query.answer()
    
    #Get choosed button
    choosed_button = query.data
    if(choosed_button == 'math_btn'):

        query.edit_message_text(text='✅You selected the Math Button✅')
        # HERE the ConversationHandler should get triggered!
        #
        #... More code is under here. But not relevant!
```

**BTW: I use python-telegram-bot library!**

Reference docs of [ConversationHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CallbackQueryHandler or ConversationHandler for a message sent from bot class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998849/callbackqueryhandler-or-conversationhandler-for-a-message-sent-from-bot-class)

Comment: @CallMeStag Kinda. If I have multiple functions do I need to make a ConversationHandler for each function or can I use the same for more than one function? If yes how?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Are you asking if you can use multiple handlers as entry points? Yes, that's why `entry_points` get's a list.

Comment: Yes, thats what I asked! Thank you very much!